# Mysql; if-else condition in Query and result added to a new variable

Tags: mysql, zend-db

I have two tables i.e Vendors and Products

**Vendors**:
id 
charges_by (enum 'Order','Product')
extra_fee_per_product
fee_per_order

**Prodcuts**:
cost
msrp
fee_per_product 
vendor_id

I want to see all the products whose margin is less than 100 and greater than 50

Formulae to calculate margin in my project is:

```
If(Vendors.charges_by=='Order') then 
   Vendor Fees = Products.Cost + Vendors.fee_per_order +
   Vendors.extra_fee_per_product
ElSE IF(Vendors.charges_by=='Product') then Vendor Fees = Products.Cost + 
   Vendors.fee_per_product + Vendors.extra_fee_per_product

Gross Profit = Products.msrp - Vendor Fees
```

Now we calculate Gross Profit =

```
Margin = (Gross Profit / MSRP) * 100
```

I have implemented search in a list and i want to see these records in one query of MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT prod_id, (((msrp + 0.0) - (
  CASE
    WHEN v.charges_by = 'Order'
    THEN p.cost + v.fee_per_order + v.extra_fee_per_product
    WHEN v.charges_by = 'Product' 
    THEN p.cost + p.fee_per_product + v.extra_fee_per_product
  END
)) / msrp) * 100 AS Margin
FROM Vendors v
INNER JOIN Products p
ON v.id = p.vendor_id
HAVING Margin BETWEEN 10 AND 100
```

**Working Fiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddbaf2/8

The critical part here is `msrp + 0.0`, it has been done to treat the calculation as a floating point value instead of a number.

Answer (score 0):

this you looking for ?

```
   SELECT (msrp - if(Vendors.charges_by=='Order',Products.Cost + Vendors.fee_per_order +
           Vendors.extra_fee_per_product,Products.Cost + 
           Vendors.fee_per_product + Vendors.extra_fee_per_product)/ msrp )*100 as `Margin` 
   FROM Vendors 
   INNER JOIN Prodcuts ON Vendors.id = Prodcuts.vendor_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.cost, t1.msrp, t1.fee_per_product, t1.vendor_id from
((select (((p.msrp-(p.cost+v.fee_per_order+v.extra_fee_per_product))/p.msrp)*100) as margin
p.cost as cost, p.msrp as msrp, p.fee_per_product as fee_per_product, p.vendor_id as vendor_id
from products p inner join vendors v
on(v.id = p.vendor_id)
where v.charges_by in ['order', 'product']) as t1)
where t1.margin < 100 and t1.margin > 50;
```

Try this...best of luck!